# Google Nexus 7 2013 (6.0.1) no longer works with All 4 streaming (UK)

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, video-streaming

I have a venerable Google Nexus 7 2013 (OS 6.0.1) that I still use. It works well - or did, up until a few days ago.

One of the things I use it for is streaming - BBC iPlayer, ITV hub, All 4, youtube etc.

It has been fine up to now, when all of a sudden it will not stream All 4. It will stream everything else and all other internet connectivity is fine.

The local network is wifi (2.4/5GHz) connecting with a TP-Link ADSL router to Plusnet Fibre.

Initially I though it was a temporary All 4 problem. But other devices (Android and PC) on the same network stream fine.

First I restarted the app, then cleared the cache and data, then restarted the router, then I reinstalled the app, then finally I did a factory reset. None had any effect. The error is 'An error has occurred - Touch to retry'. Retry has no effect. Unfortunately I do not have access to another wifi network I can try.

I am completely out of ideas. It must be software, all hardware appears fine. The summary is:

- Nexus 7 2013 running Android 6.0.1 (not rooted).
- Will not stream All 4 (UK).
- Will stream everything else.
- All other internet connection is fine.
- Other devices (PC, Android) on the same network will stream All 4.
- Resetting everything had no effect.
- Worked fine up to 7-10 days ago.

Any suggestion as to the cause of this would be welcome.

Comment: Could be an expired intermediate- or root-certificate which which has been updated but is not present on your device. Enable development option and Android debug bridge on your device and connect the devoce via USB to an PC with Android SDK installed.  Monitor errors that occur on the output of `adb logcat` that occur when you start the app and try to play a video.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Did that, captured logcat output (via Android Studio)  from hitting 'retry'. There's an awful lot of it (2,200 lines) and not at all sure what I am looking for? The link to the captured file is https://drive.google.com/file/d/1uh-roAJzfAunyFPr84_dD_EE1SPKrTqL/view?usp=sharing, or if you could suggest to me what to look for, I'd look.

Comment: I would assume that the `DrmSessionException` by `ExoPlayer` (a popular video viewing component) is causing your trouble. The actual reason why this error occurs is unknown. Therefore the only chance to get this fixed is contact the author(s) of the app which fails and provide the log you have created.

Comment: Thanks, I#ll look into that!

Comment: Reported this to All 4 support. No answer at all. Not unexpected, really.

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem with my nexus 7, worked faultlessly with streaming vids ...untill the 2nd week in Jan 2021 when overnight could no longer get the vids to work, just got a blank screen. I think the reason is that that was the exact time adobe started blocking all computers and devices with flash player. since then ive not had a decent downloadable live streaming vid or web cam - i pay for many of the sites i use.
even my new win10 pc has problems with streaming video whereas before jan 10th and the adobe flash blocking all worked fine !!

Comment: Interesting. Different problem though, I think. Mine stopped in 9/2020, Flash was still OK then. Never managed to fix it, never got a response from All4.